# "Mes grands-parents" or "Mes grand-parents" ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, mots-composés

Can anyone explain to me what is the correct answer and why?

I don't know if I have to put an "S" or not.

Answer (score 3):

Les mots composés d'un nom et d'un adjectif accordent les deux termes... en principe !
La langue française réserve des exceptions :

> Mes grands-parents (accord)

certes, mais :

> Ma grand-mère (pas d'accord)

- Parce que *Ma grande mère* veut dire que "ma maman est grande"
- *Ma grande-mère* avec le trait d'union et l'accord devient aberrant : *grand* a ici un double sens (taille et antériorité d'un ancêtre) qui justifie l'exception : l'accord ne se fait pas.

---

***P.S.*** Référence extraite du petit Robert:

Dans les expressions sous forme masculine, au féminin on retrouve *grand* sans `e`: *Grand-rue, grand-messe, grand-croix*...

Au pluriel cela donne :

> Mes ***grands-pères*** et ***grands-mères*** sont mes ***grands-parents*** (ces derniers s'écrivent toujours  au pluriel).

*Grand* est ici pris dans son acception : "Qui a une importance sociale ou politique".

Comment: Peut-on en conclure que, le `grand` ne s'accordant pas, on écrit "Mes grand-mères" ? Conséquemment, quid de mes "Mes grand(s)-pères"  ? Il semble que cela fasse débat

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/grands-parents) is the Collins English/French dictionary on the subject.

Check out rule number three [here](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/learning-french/48840-plural-form-of-french-compound-nouns/) - Compound nouns written with a noun and an adjective both require an “s".

Another example (from memory) is rond-point (roundabout/rotary) - the plural is ronds-points.